# scaffoldBackgroundColor does not seem to set color properly in MaterialApp in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a material app which uses a theme built on light theme.  I am changing scaffoldBackgroundColor to a specific color which does not seem to take.  The background on the page is black rather than grey.

build() method of the app which identifies this app as a MaterialApp:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: '???',
      theme: appTheme,
      routes: {
        AppRoutes.login: (context) {
          return new LoginPage(
            authenticator: authenticate,
          );
        },
        AppRoutes.home: (context) {
          return new HomePage(
            appState: appState,
            accountRepository: widget.accountRepository,
            authRepository: widget.authRepository,
          );
        },
      },
    );
  }
```

Theme - here I am reusing the light Theme as the basis for my new theme which changing the scaffoldBackgroundColor to a custom color:

```dart
const coolGreyHi = const Color.fromARGB(40,30,20,66);

final ThemeData appTheme = _buildAppTheme();

ThemeData _buildAppTheme() {
  final ThemeData base = new ThemeData.light();
  return base.copyWith(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: coolGreyHi,
    inputDecorationTheme: new InputDecorationTheme(
      border: new OutlineInputBorder(),
    )
  );
}
```

build method of the Page where the background should be grey:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(          
      body: new SafeArea(
        child: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40.0, 0.0, 40.0, 0.0),
                child: new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Image.asset('images/image.png'),
                    new SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                    new TextField(
                      controller: _uidTextController, decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "you@yourdomain.com",
                        labelText: "Email Address",
                      ),

                    ),
                    new SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                    new TextField(
                      controller: _pwdTextController, decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Password",
                        labelText: "Password",
                      ),
                    ),
                    new SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                    new ButtonBar(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new FlatButton(
                          child: new Text("SIGN UP"),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                        new RaisedButton(
                          child: new Text("SIGN IN"),
                          elevation: 8.0,
                          onPressed: () {
                            authenticator(_uidTextController.text, _pwdTextController.text).then((bool isAuthenticated) {
                              if (isAuthenticated)
                                Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(AppRoutes.home, (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ), 
    );
  }
```

Comment: this problem can be solved following documentation's insctructions

Comment: @DiegoMarquina, I thought I was but I am not getting the desired results.  Unless I am missing something, either you are mentioning documentation snippets that i have not seen yet or this is a different situation.  What specific snippets of documentation are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

I did some further checking and it seems like some colors, even those within Flutter palette like Colors.black54 or Colros.black45 do appear as black on my emulator.  I have not tested them on the physical device.  I am not sure if the problem is with the display or with the emulator and how it is set up but a color like Colros.grey does appear normally.
To summarize, setting the scaffoldBackgroundColor on the ThemeData works as designed but some colors may not appear accurately (i.e. as black in my instance).  Not sure if the problem is with the display or the emulator.

Comment: If you're using an emulator and getting graphics bugs try `flutter run  --enable-software-rendering `

Answer (score 0):

Please use a recent Flutter version (e.g. `beta` or `dev`) channel. You can then use the `backgroundColor` property on `Scaffold`, as documentation outlines it here: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold/backgroundColor.html

Comment: I am on Channel beta, v0.9.4. Dart version 2.1.0-dev.5.0.flutter-a2eb050044.  Tried backgroundColor on Scaffold - still not showing me the right color.  Removed  theme from material app while leaving the backgroundColor - still not setting it correctly.  But I tried a built in color, like Colors.cyan and it works fine so I think the problem might be with my color definition of const coolGreyHi = const Color.fromARGB(40,30,20,66).  Care to comment?

Comment: Check the docs for Color: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html . Perhaps it’s simply a incorrect color definition.